# Consumo de memoria IIS 8

Tags: servidor, iis, asp

Subi minha aplicação e verifiquei que ela estava muito lenta, e no IIS Worker Process o consumo de memoria não diminui, por exemplo: eu fiz uns testes e o consumo subiu para 1 GB, isso com 6 abas abertas somente, faz meia hora que não acesso o site e ainda está com o consumo de 1GB, Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Alto consumo de memória não necessariamente é o culpado pela lentidão. Qual o total de memória na máquina onde você está fazendo a medição? É difícil responder a sua pergunta sem saber exatamente como é o seu aplicativo. Pode explicar em linhas gerais o que ele faz?